# 「感謝のしようもありません。」の「しよう」はどういう意味ですか？

Tags: translation

> 「感謝のしようもありません。」

The sentence translates as "I can't thank you enough".
I read on the forums that 「しよう」 is a casual volitional form of 「する」.
Does that mean it's an even more casual form of 「したい」?

How would you literally translate this? My attempt would look like this:

> "Even the feelings that I want to feel don't exist (or aren't). "

Sounds pretty intense to me already. How close was that?

What are other ways to use 「しよう」?
Can you say 「これをしよう」 for "I want that"?

Comment: 感動 or 感謝?  「感動のしようもありません」 does not mean "I can't thank you enough."

Answer (score 6):

The しよう is not the volitional form of する, but "a way of doing~~" (=「し[様]{よう}」).

> 感謝のしようもありません。

*lit.* There's no way of thanking.
→ I can't thank you enough.

<sub>By the way, volitional しよう is pronounced [しよう]{LHL} and し様, [しよう]{LHH}.</sub>

---

The [様]{よう}, attached to the continuative form (連用形) of a verb, can mean "a way of (doing~~)" (≂ [方法]{ほうほう}). A few examples from [プログレッシブ和英中辞典](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%82%88%E3%81%86/#je-77747):

> この時計は[直]{なお}し[様]{よう}がない。 This watch cannot be repaired.
>   これだけでは[考]{かんが}え[様]{よう}がない。 We can't consider it without more information.
>   [手]{て}の[下]{くだ}し[様]{よう}がなかった。 There was nothing to be done about it.

> Can you say 「これをしよう」 for "I want that"?

「これをしよう」 would be interpreted  as "I'll do this." or "Let's do this."
You could say 「あれがほしい」 to mean "I want that."